# How does mean and SD change when squared

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say we have a random variable $X$ whose mean is 10 and whose SD is 20. 
Now we have $Y = 3X^2$

What is the mean of Y? If that is possible with given information

Comment: The mean of $Y $ can be computed using the identity $Var (Y)=E (Y^2)-E (Y)^2$. But its variance could be anything, even infinite.

Comment: So since variance here can be anything then the mean can technically be anything too right since it depends on variance, thus we cannot solve for mean with just the info provided.

Comment: I should have said that $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=E(Y)-E(X)^2$. Thus $E(Y)=Var(X)+E(X)^2$. Nonetheless $Var(Y)$ could be anything because it is related to $E(X^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

By @Ian's Comment, we have $400 = V(X) = E(X^2) - 10^2,$ so
$E(X^2) = 500$ and $E(3X^2) = 1500.$

---

Here are two examples, in case they are helpful.

If $X \sim Norm(\mu = 10, \sigma = 20).$
The square of a $standard$ normal random variable is $Chisq(df = 1),$ and the mean and variance
of that distribution are known. Presumably, you can take it from there to find $E(3X^2)$ from the distribution of $X^2.$

A brief simulation in R can give
an answer (correct to maybe 2 or 3 significant digits)
based on a million realizations of $X$.

```
 x = rnorm(10^6, 10, 20);  mean(3*x^2)
 ## 1503.02
```

Also, if $X \sim Gamma(shape = 4, rate = 1/5)$ we have
$E(X) = 20$ and $SD(X) = 10,$ so that $E(3X^2) = 1500.$
But in this case the particulars of the distribution
theory are messier.

```
 x = rgamma(10^6, 4, 1/5);  mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 19.99749
 ## 10.00549
 mean(3*x^2)
 ## 1500.028
```